# Modify metadata of object on server-side only using a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Is there a way to modify/add metadata fields to an object uploaded to Firestore Storage in the onFinalize trigger function? There is documentation on how to perform this operation on the client side but not on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is plenty of documentation for the server side libraries. If you're deploying code to Cloud Functions using the Firebase CLI, that means you're probably using the Cloud Storage node SDK.  The API documentation for that is [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/), and the general documentation is [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage).  In the general documentation there are even plenty of examples to get you started.  One of the samples is called "storage set file metadata".

Comment: Thanks Doug - I didn't even know that the two were related. It would be good to put links to it from Firebase Storage Documentation.

Comment: Check out the first paragraph in the main product doc page [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).  *"You can use our SDKs to store images, audio, video, or other user-generated content. On the server, you can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage), to access the same files."*

Comment: And if you found this answer helpful, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks - I have accepted the answer but I could not upvote because I don't have enough reputation points yet.